# Can I run line_profiler on python module?

Tags: python, python-unittest, line-profiler

I have a module named my_module with the following structure.

```
.
└── my_module
    ├── main.py
    └── test.py
```

Here, I use python -m my_module.test, in order to run the test because it uses relative import.

Then how can I run line_profiler, memory_profiler on a module? (it can be pytest)

Followings are what I have tried

> 1st approach

```
python -m cProfile -m my_module.test   # works -> but I want line_profiler
```

> 2nd approach

```
import line_profiler
import unittest

profiler = line_profiler.LineProfiler()

class PageTester(unittest.TestCase):
  @profiler
  def test_abc(self):
    print(1)

if __name__ == "__main__"
  unittest.main(module='page.test')
  profiler.print_stats()           # doesn't print anything
```

Comment: Your code sample is wrong. What's `foo.lprof` ?

Comment: I updated the question, it should have been blank.

Comment: I think your `if` statement is wrong -- should be `if __name__ == "__main__":`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `line_profiler` with `unittest.TestCase`.
Just move the `print_stats` to `tearDownClass` of the `TestCase`

```
import unittest
import line_profiler

profiler = line_profiler.LineProfiler()

class PageTester(unittest.TestCase):
  @profiler
  def test_abc(self):
      print("abc")
      #profiler.print_stats() 
  
  @profiler
  def test_def(self):
      self.test_abc()

  @classmethod
  def tearDownClass(cls):  
     profiler.print_stats() 
      
if __name__ == "__main__":
  unittest.main(module='page.test')
```

---

The output is what is expected:

```
abc
abc
Timer unit: 1e-06 s

Total time: 1.3e-05 s
File: /root/page/test.py
Function: test_abc at line 10

Line #      Hits         Time  Per Hit   % Time  Line Contents
==============================================================
    10                                             @profiler
    11                                             def test_abc(self):
    12         2         13.0      6.5    100.0        print("abc")

Total time: 9e-06 s
File: /root/page/test.py
Function: test_def at line 15

Line #      Hits         Time  Per Hit   % Time  Line Contents
==============================================================
    15                                             @profiler
    16                                             def test_def(self):
    17         1          9.0      9.0    100.0        self.test_abc()
```